# Finding files that do not have a particular line

Tags: command-line, unix, grep

The following command lists all files (with lines) that have the mentioned line:

```
$ grep  "\[oow\] running" *.log
```

However, what I want to know is all the *.log files that do **not** have that line. Using the `-v` option to grep prints innumerous number of other lines. But I only want the file that does not have the mentioned line. How does one normally do this in Unix/Mac (in command line of course)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the -L option:

```
-L, --files-without-match
       Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
       file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The
       scanning will stop on the first match.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -L "\[oow\] running" *.log
```